# How can I get macromedia flash 5?

Tags: 2d, flash

I was used to draw and develop Flash games in the 2000's. For me that's the best vector drawing tool for 2d games ever, better than illustrator and new flash recent versions.

Can anybody tell me how can I get my hands on the old Macromedia Flash 5?

Comment: I started with Flash 4 and quite honestly can't find much of a difference in the drawing tools of the most recent version. Sure, they added some capabilities, but the tools from the old versions are still in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question does not really match the gamedev.stackexchange.com rules.

However I like old Flash versions too to make some vectorial draws and I keep my old CDs (including [FutureSplash Animator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FutureSplash_Animator)) so I can play with them. I am almost sure you can get an official CD with serial number on websites such ebay for few dollars.

I can see two of them for less than 5$ [here](http://tinyurl.com/axu4fw2) at the time I am writing those lines.